# Code signing certificate with lifetime policy not working

Tags: code-signing-certificate, authenticode

I have created a self-signed code signing certificate with the Microsoft lifetime OID 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.13. The certificate has expired, but the signed program continues to work normally. I was hoping the program would stop working or that Windows would give some kind of a warning. I am getting neither. Where am I going wrong ?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I put the Lifetime OID in the wrong place. It has to be a part of the Enhanced Key Usage attribute. The attribute then becomes:

Code Signing (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3)
Lifetime Signing (1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.13)